# onreadystatechange is too slow

Tags: javascript, ajax

Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why AJAX callbacks are TOO slow? Here's code:

```
function new_xmlhttp() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function ajax_get(data, args) {

    xmlhttp = new_xmlhttp();

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "functions.php?" + data, true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // OK.
            alert(args);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Sometimes it takes 2-3 seconds to load (data is max 10 bytes long.)

Tested on Firefox and Chrome under Linux.

Comment: It means that your server is taking that long to respond.

Comment: Take a look at the developer console and check the speed and size of the request. Sounds like you have a slow server.

Comment: No, I don't. Without callback, it's extremely fast.

Comment: That's...debatable. Try it without the callback, and then look at the *network* tab of your developer tools, to see exactly how long the server takes to respond. In some cases you can see the same result by visiting the URL directly in your browser.

Comment: by visiting directly, it shows result instantly. but with AJAX callback, it takes like 2-3 seconds or more to process. without callback, I mean with synchronization enabled, it does fast (like direct loading page.) why?..

Comment: Nobody had same problem?.... HELP!

Comment: Currently having the same problem with angularjs.